# How do I change the naming convention when VS creates a method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am designing a windows form and double clicked on a button which creates an Event Handler in the code.

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {..}
```

Now with the above, button is lower cased and I would prefer if Visual Studio creates the method with Capital Casing.

e.g.

```
 private void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {..}
```

How do I change the configuration for VS?

Edit: Is there no way to force VS to have a capital letter when it creates a method regardless of what the original component's id is?

Comment: Change the ID of the control first?

Comment: Instead of double-clicking you can input a name manually. Or you can change it afterwards with the Rename function, which will change the name throughout your code.

Comment: @HansPassant button1 was an example which I used for simplicity's sake... My component's names starts with lowercase because they tend to be private and it's what I am used to. My question specifically was how to force VS to have all methods that are created to start with a Capital letter REGARDLESS of what the ID being used. After some thought, this was probably designed so Button cancelButton will generate a different method than Button CancelButton.

Answer (score 0):

As Steve mentioned

You can change the `ID` of the Control

if you don't want to change the `Id` of control but the method name should be like this

`private void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {..}`

then See this Example markup and change like that

`<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="test" OnClick="Button1_click" />`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be possible after some thought.

This was probably designed in that way so if someone creates two buttons: Button1 and button1, VS will be able to create event handlers for these two buttons on its own and not cause an error.

```
private void button1_click(...)

private void Button1_click(...)
```